# Bash: add column based on command

Tags: bash

In Bash, is there a simple way to take a column, run a bash command on the value, then append the result as a new column?

As a simple (and contrived) example, lets say I want a list of symlinks in the current directory and the targets they point to. The awk equivalent might be something like this:

```
ls | awk '{ "readlink -f "$1 | getline target; print $1, target }'
```

But that is a mouthful. I would prefer a tool design explicitly for this task. Something akin to `xargs`:

```
ls | add-column readlink -f
```

And the output would be:

```
A.txt /path/to/A.txt
B.txt /path/to/B.txt
```

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: I hope you don't *literally* mean to use this with `ls` -- that's a bad idea for several reasons; see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Note that I deliberately said 'and contrived'

Answer (score 1):

Easily done, though it's safer for the name to use an underscore rather than a dash (the [relevant POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231) guarantees only "underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set" to be supported [in function names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05)):

```
add_column() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$line" "$("$@" "$line")"
  done
}

ls -1 | add_column readlink -f --
```

Note that [output of `ls` is not suitable for programmatic use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), so this particular example should be just that -- an example -- only.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a simple `while` loop:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$file" "$(readlink -- "$file")"
    done | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Note I am using `find` instead of `ls` because it has the `-print0` that can handle filename with line breaks. Also, this will not produce the correct output formatting if any symlink or any of their targets contain a tab.

Comment: Using `echo -e` here is bad form -- surely if the content contains a literal backslash followed by a literal `t`, you don't want to change those from being literals. (Also, [the POSIX definition for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html) doesn't require `-e` to be available at all -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section suggesting `printf` instead -- and it isn't available even in bash if some optional flags, environment variables [or compile-time options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Optional-Features.html) are enabled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right, I changed it to a `printf`.